# Unable to launch two windows from two different threads

Tags: c++, raylib

I am using RayLib and I have this code simply to create a window:

```
void start_window(std::string windowName){

    InitWindow(800, 450, windowName.c_str());
    SetTargetFPS(60);
    rlFPCamera cam;
    cam.Setup(45,Vector3{ 1, 0, 0 });
    cam.SetCameraPosition((Vector3){1.0f, 500.0f, 1.0f});
    cam.MoveSpeed.z = 100;
    cam.MoveSpeed.x = 100;
    cam.FarPlane = 5000;


    Material matDefault = LoadMaterialDefault();
    Material matRed = LoadMaterialDefault();
    Material matGreen = LoadMaterialDefault();
    matDefault.maps[MATERIAL_MAP_DIFFUSE].color = BLUE;
    matRed.maps[MATERIAL_MAP_DIFFUSE].color = RED;
    matGreen.maps[MATERIAL_MAP_DIFFUSE].color = GREEN;

    Model cube = LoadModelFromMesh(GenMeshCube(5,5,5));
    int width = 3072;
    int height = 3072;

    // Dynamic memory allocation to store pixels data (Color type)
    Color *pixels = (Color *)malloc(width*height*sizeof(Color));

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            if (((x/16+y/16)/1)%2 == 0) pixels[y*width + x] = WHITE;
            else pixels[y*width + x] = BLUE;
        }
    }
    Image checkedIm = {
            .data = pixels,             // We can assign pixels directly to data
            .width = width,
            .height = height,
            .mipmaps = 1,
            .format = PIXELFORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED_R8G8B8A8,
    };

    Texture2D checked = LoadTextureFromImage(checkedIm);

    Model terrain = LoadModel("Resources/Terrains/TestingGround.obj");
    terrain.materials[0].maps[MATERIAL_MAP_DIFFUSE].texture = checked;
    Vector3 cubePosition = {2.50f, 3.0f, 2.50f};

    UnloadImage(checkedIm);
    while (!WindowShouldClose())    // Detect window close button or ESC key
    {
        cam.Update();

        float offsetThisFrame = 100.0f*GetFrameTime();


        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(SKYBLUE);
        cam.BeginMode3D();
        DrawGrid(1000, 1.0f);
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_SPACE))
        {
            cam.SetCameraPosition((Vector3){cam.GetCameraPosition().x, cam.GetCameraPosition().y+offsetThisFrame, cam.GetCameraPosition().z});
        }
        else if (IsKeyDown(KEY_Z))
        {
            cam.SetCameraPosition((Vector3){cam.GetCameraPosition().x, cam.GetCameraPosition().y-offsetThisFrame, cam.GetCameraPosition().z});
        }
        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_SPACE))
        {
            cubePosition = {cubePosition.x, cubePosition.y + 5, cubePosition.z};
        }
        VibraniumEngine::DrawModel(cube, (Vector3){50.30f, 12.32f, 40.7f}, 1, RED);
        VibraniumEngine::DrawModel(cube, (Vector3){68.8f, 8.8f, 74.7f}, 1, RED);
        VibraniumEngine::DrawModel(cube, (Vector3){15.52f, 11.65f, 84.51f}, 1, RED);
        VibraniumEngine::DrawModel(cube, cubePosition, 1, BLUE);

        DrawModelEx(terrain, (Vector3){0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},(Vector3){0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, 0.0f,(Vector3){1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, WHITE);

        EndMode3D();

        DrawFPS( 10, 10);
        DrawText("Press H to hide the Map Window.", 10, 32, 12, GREEN);
        DrawText(TextFormat("Camera Pos: X: %3.2fY:  %3.2f Z: %3.2f",
                            cam.GetCameraPosition().x * -1,
                            cam.GetCameraPosition().y,
                            cam.GetCameraPosition().z), 10, 52, 12, BLACK);
        EndDrawing();
    }
    UnloadModel(cube);
    CloseWindow();
}
```

The code above executes and runs well.

If I try to start the above code with only one thread like this for example:

```
std::thread game1 (&start_window, "test");
```

It works perfectly. 1 Windows is created. So far, so good.
However, if I try to do:

```
std::thread game1 (&start_window, "test");
std::thread game2 (&start_window, "test 2");
```

This does not work. No windows start at all. Any idea why and is it even possible to start two RayLib windows from two threads, if so how can I do it?

Comment: for a start, check the return values of all those function calls. (If there is one)

Comment: how does `WindowShouldClose` know which window you are referring to.

Comment: Most GUI/windowing frameworks have an underpinning assumption that all windows created and controlled (e.g. windows event loops) by a process are handled (or at least coordinated) by a  single thread (e.g. only one thread runs an event loop).  This has a range of effects - including unexpected behaviours if multiple unsynchronised threads create windows.   That is almost certainly true of raylib.